# Can meteor.js web framework support a social networking architecture effectively?

Tags: meteor, social-networking

So I'm new to node.js, javascript frameworks, and meteor.com. I'm trying to learn how to build social networks, and I'm naive/struggling to understand why Meteor.js (meteor.com) wouldn't be able to do all the great things you see now that twitter, facebook, instagram are doing?

There's the comet technology between client/server, authentication configs, asynchronous coding for scaling and performance, and built on top of node.js.

I'm trying to learn more about long polling, comet, gridFS or how files are stored, and in general things like replication sets, and sharding to help with performance (esp since Redhat has this openshift platform that we can build our own private clouds with).

I have some computer science background, but it seems like magic, so what am I missing? If you all could think of a few buzz words that make a social network tick that Meteor.js doesn't support, what would it be?

I hear things about parallel and concurrency (webworkers fixes that in part, no?), websockets, that high level languages like python or java are better off supporting. There's only one to learn my answers, and thats by doing, but thought someone could sway me one way or the other via this thread. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question encompasses a really broad idea and just focusing on using meteor alone would solve this issue. Here are a few points to consider:

1. I don't think this framework would be a good starting point to learn long-polling, gridFS, etc etc. Meteor aims to be a framework that tends to be more of an ecosystem of packages e.g. you can certainly roll your own aformentioned strategies -- however for dynamic updates, Meteor uses its own Data Delivery Protocol (DDP) supported/implemented by (surprise) a good bunch of core packages such as Spark.
2. Parallel processing and concurrency *can* be better off done using other languages, but why not ***with***? Since Meteor is largely based on `node.js`, and `node.js` is really good with the aforementioned stuff plus it can play *very* well with other languages so you could integrate smoothly. Meteor doesn't really require you purely rely on it, as other languages would say the same thing. It's all in the general engineering / planning for your project. [There are already lots of really good stuff out there that rely on Meteor](http://madewith.meteor.com/), join in! don't be afraid. It all boils down to planning (and the courage/perseverance to pull it off, of course).
3. Right now, we cannot tell if Meteor would be incapable of the usual *great* stuff by gigantic websites. Sure, we can do live updates, (its own kind of) publish/subscribe patterns, and powerful stuff to **boost development** (look at the seven [core concepts](http://docs.meteor.com/#concepts) of meteor to best understand this). It is *not* impossible to replicate what is already out there, really. We can only say it with uncertainty at the moment mainly because.. (see next point)
4. The framework is so young! it's still at 0.6.x at the time of writing. Please take time to look at the [Meteor Roadmap](https://trello.com/board/meteor-roadmap/508721606e02bb9d570016ae) to see how things are going in terms of broader support for persistence/databases, performance considerations, and the official DDP specification.

I hope I have answered your enquiry (and more, I hope). I'm really excited for meteor myself as it could easily be the next big thing. We have a couple of (for-)production projects using Meteor as well, so you're getting direct insight from a person who has done quite a bit of hacking (and tons of research and first-hand experience) in Meteor. Not that i'm saying i'm an expert or so, it's just so much fun to work with Meteor and i'm totally not kidding you.

Hope this helps!

P.S.: Fair warning though, resources and documentation is really sparse at this point. I try to contribute to the community as much as I can about it (one of my starting points is here, on SO).